# Can Facebook Pixel detect metadata of content loaded dynamically(SPA)?

Tags: facebook, schema, single-page-application, pixel

We have an angularJS ecommerce website with a Facebook pixel installed - we would like to create a Facebook Product Catalogue using the Facebook pixel as a data source.

According to Facebook we need to add the required metadata tags to each product page we want to add to the catalogue.

Sound simple enough but our website is a single page application so viewing a product goes like this...

1. User clicks on product link
2. Application switches to 'Product Page' state and renders a 'loading' html template
3. An api call is made to get the products details
4. The api call completes and we update the template html with the product details(and required metadata tags) and remove the 'loading' element

So my question is, will the Facebook pixel be smart enough to detect the metadata tags once they are added to the page in step 4?

Or will the pixel see the page as it initally loads(with no product data and a 'loading' div)?

I have contacted facebook support regarding this but they actually directed me here!

Thanks

Comment: in general, facebook does not parse javascript. but did you already test it?

Comment: The scraper doesn’t care for JavaScript when you let it scrape a URL - but the pixel “is” JavaScript already, and has full access to the current state of the DOM. https://www.facebook.com/business/help/887775018036966 says, _“Your pixel fires each time it tracks an event and captures information about the product involved.”_ - so I would _assume_ that it does so by gathering that information from the DOM. But as @luschen said - try it and find out. Install the Chrome Facebook Pixel Helper extension if you don’t have it already, then you can see what values your pixel sends.